# What is the `foo => ({...})` construct in Apollo options functions?

Tags: apollo

For example:

```
apolloServer(request => ({
  schema: typeDefinitionArray,
  graphiql: true,
  context: request.session
}))
```

http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/tools.html

I know `=>` means es6 function with bound `this`, but what does the `()` after the `=>` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you skip the `()` then it will be ambiguous if it's a body of a lambda or an object literal that you want to return. So it's either

```
apolloServer(request => {
  return {
    schema: typeDefinitionArray,
    graphiql: true,
    context: request.session
}})
```

or

```
apolloServer(request => ({
  schema: typeDefinitionArray,
  graphiql: true,
  context: request.session
}))
```